# Is it possible to code an app capable of running in the background on MIT App Inventor?

Tags: app-inventor

I am coding an app on MIT App inventor that detects when someone is walking and on their phone at the same time. One aspect of the app that my group wants to include is having the app run in the background and detect when other apps are running in the foreground. I looked on the MIT App Inventor forum and found no answers as to how I can do this. Is creating an app that runs in the background possible on MIT App Inventor?

I looked at solutions in other coding languages for some potential insight and found something about an activity manager working in java, but even if this code is somewhat transferable I wouldn't know how to apply it to get the desired result.

Comment: no, see also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/run$20background%7Csort:date

Answer (score 0):

Background services are currently not available in App Inventor. There are workarounds such as using Clock component to continuously run and execute a task. Other alternative is to keep the screen on (using extension). However, these approaches could potentially result in higher battery usage.